# saveJsonToEs takes too much time to process each element even node is not overloaded

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch

```
JavaEsSpark.saveJsonToEs(JavaRDD<String>, HashMap<String, String>)
```

taking too much time to process each element. 
I have 50000 elements and it takes hours to process all of them.
I have below configuration.

```
ES_BATCH_SIZE_BYTES = 1mb,
ES_BATCH_SIZE_ENTRIES = 1000,
ES_BATCH_WRITE_REFRESH = false,
ES_BATCH_WRITE_RETRY_COUNT = 10,
ES_BATCH_WRITE_RETRY_WAIT = 30s
```

.
I tried to find [solution from thread - SPARK-7122](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-7122) which suggest updating Spark version to 1.5 or above and I am already using 1.6

My cluster or node are not overloaded and they are healthy.

Comment: Regarding ES, you might want to have a look [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/tune-for-indexing-speed.html) for tips on improving the indexing speed

Comment: Solution worked for me: Spark UI explained that where exactly my process was consuming time. It wasn't ElasticSearch but it was heavy Spark algorithm which was holding things back.
We have changed submit.sh variables like Executer/Driver memory, Number of cores, and Executers per node which helped us to make things work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

50000 rows it will take hours you said... check what is the size of each row... It also matters... based on that you can increase/decrease the batch size like `ES_BATCH_SIZE_ENTRIES/ES_BATCH_SIZE_BYTES` .

Make sure that data is not going to one particular node while writing...
-Test performance on a single node, with a single shard and no replicas. 
Record performance under default settings so that you have a baseline to measure against.

Finally, In the spark side check your `rdd.partitions.length` if needed re partition that first for better parallelism and check other parameters like executor memory, driver memory, number of executors and cores etc...

Comment: I have 3 nodes and they have distributed traffic load. One important thing is traffic load goes high at last 45 mins from these hours long operation.
We expect 40-50 mins for these 50k files(10GB data).

Comment: "one important thing is traffic load goes high at last 45 mins " => load is going to last task. so consider repartitioning of rdd before save

Comment: repartitionNumber =finalRDD.map().getNumPartitions() / 4;
We are already repartitioning of rdd before saveJsonToEs() in above code format.

Comment: go to spark ui and see that all tasks are loaded with your re-partitioning or not. if not then you need to further re-partition to big number than you are using currently.

Comment: Sure, I will. I also want to add a detailed comment about my issue so It can be helpful for others in future.

Comment: Solution worked for me: Spark UI explained that where exactly my process was consuming time. It wasn't ElasticSearch but it was heavy Spark algorithm which was holding things back.
We have changed submit.sh variables like Executer/Driver memory, Number of cores, and Executers per node which helped us to make things work.
Thank You @Ram